# Highcharts, ROR, how to get labels working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am trying to get labels to appear on my column chart.

JavaScript

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.highchartDATA = '<%= @data %>';
<% end %>
```

dashboard.html.erb

```
<script>
 $(function () {


        $('#notes_chart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                [0, '#2a2a2b'],
                [1, '#3e3e40']
         ]
      },

            },
            title: {
                text: 'Total Notes By Class Module'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Notes Table'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total Number',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify',
                    style: {
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ''
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
           name: 'Number of Notes By Class Module',
           data: <%= @data %> 
          }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note.rb

```
def self.getData
    data = []
    self.subject_types.each do |type|
      data << self.type_count(type)
    end
    data
  end

  private

  def self.subject_types
    pluck(:subject_type).uniq
  end

  def self.type_count(type)
    where(subject_type: type).count
  end
end
```

Controller: notes_controller.rb

```
def dashboard
    @data = Note.highchart_data
  end
```

The graph is populated from the following model:

```
create_table "classmodules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "student_id"
    t.string   "subject"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Currently this works. However I can not get the labels to appear on the column chart. How do I get the labels to appear automatically? All that is there is 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.... Thanks!

Comment: Do you want data labels to appear or are you referring to labels on the x and y axes?

Comment: Thanks. I am referring to labels on the x axis. All I get is 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. Can I get them to automatically update from the model/table?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

For data, I believe you are passing in an array of the type counts. Since it is a 1 dimensional array, the x-axis is being treated as the location in that array.

If you want the subject labels on the x-axis, then you should pass in the following format for data [[subject, count]...].

See: [http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Ccolumn%3E.data)

Comment: You mean in the view? Thanks. What goes in to categories[], ?

Comment: Yes, I meant in your note.rb file. If you pass in a 2 dimensional array with subject label, count, then you don't need to populate the categories array on the x axis. If you want to do a single dimensional array then you would pass in your labels as categories on the x-axis (same result as long as you have only 1 series)

Comment: Thanks. The subjects are populated by the user. This complicates things. I don't want to have to assign labels in code. I'd just like the labels to show up automatically.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. You can pass the subjects in with the counts to data in a 2 dimensional array. This works unless you expect subject names to change when the counts (data) doesn't change. If subject names change dynamically, then you would have to listen for those changes and update the highchart data accordingly.

Comment: It's a pickle. I am trying different things but can't get the labels to show. There must be a way.